# Node.js - Build a Tic Tac Toe game with a Postgresql database

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to Node.js. In the past I mainly build webapps with Python and Django.

I need to build an app that is like the Tic Tac Toe game.

I will need to have in the webapp:

- PostgreSQL Database
- Authentication
- Socket.io

My questions:

1. What web framework should I use? (Expressjs?)
2. What authentication package should I use that will be compatible
   with PostgreSQL?
3. What should I use to manage the models? There is some package that
   does migrations automatically?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Nice to meet you. I also now running node.js.
I want to share my knowlege :).

To use dbms. U need to use module.
Here is postgres module for node.js ranking.
https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/postgresql

pg & persist is most popular module.

about web programming.
Express + Jade combination is most popular.
and u also need frontend like angular.js

rather than postgres, u can also consider mongodb.

mongo + express + node.js is popular combination.
http://www.mean.io/ is full packaged framework for this.
i hope this will be helpful to u.
cheers